# Alert pop up after date and time from excel met with current date and time

Tags: c#, .net

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AlertNotify\AlertNotifyNew.xlsx");
Excel._Worksheet excelSheet = excelBook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range excelRange = excelSheet.UsedRange;
int rows = excelRange.Rows.Count;
int cols = excelRange.Columns.Count;
for (int i = 2; i <= rows; i++)
{ 
  Console.WriteLine("\t");
  DateTime Cdate = DateTime.Now;
  string Cdate1 = Cdate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
  if (excelRange.Cells[i, j] != null && excelRange.Cells[i, j].text != null)
  {
    string exDate = excelRange.Cells[i, 2].text;
    string exDate1 = exDate.Trim();
    if (exDate1 == Cdate1)
    {
      string uTime = excelRange.Cells[i, 3].text;
      DateTime CTime = DateTime.Now;
      string CTime1 = CTime.ToString("HH:mm");
      if (uTime == CTime1)
      {
        Timer t1 = new Timer(onTimerTick,null,0,1000);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to pop up an alert after the current date and time met with the date and time read from the excel without using any task scheduler or Windows service i.e. Have to achieve this through program itself. I want to achieve this in console application c#.

Kindly let me know the possible ways to achieve this with some example code.

Comment: Based on the granularity - You can use Timer or a Thread/Task which will sleep for a second and then check for Time Matche

Comment: First you need to start something by yourself, some code that implements your idea and when you get stuck then you can ask for help here in StackOverflow.

Comment: thanks a lot Prateek. Am trying to achieve the same using Timer, But not getting enough idea to proceed further on how to achieve.

Comment: Thank you Llazar , I have added the code for reference.